# Can someone help me out with this question about logs? please

Tags: logarithms

$$3^{2x}-2^{2y}=17$$  Find $x+y$.

Here is what I did so far:
Let $m=3^{2x}$       and    let $n=2^{2y}$

$x=\frac{\log_3m}{2}$    ,          $y=\frac{\log_2n}2$

$$x+y= \frac{\log_3m+\log_2n}{2} $$

x+y= (base(3)17+n)+(base(2)n)/2

don't know what to do from there

Comment: I think you want to assume that $x,y$ are natural numbers, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$17=3^{2x}-2^{2y}=(3^x-2^y)(3^x+2^y)$$

and now remember $\;17\;$ is prime. I don't think logarithms are required here.

Comment: How do you know that $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @gt6989b Thank you. I don't, I just assumed as it looked straighforward. But, of course, I could be wrong. Hopefully the asked will explain.

Comment: yes it does state x,y∈ℤ. I just forgot to include it. Thank you very much